# Using If Elif Else Conditions in a For Loop to return items

Tags: python, function, loops, class, conditional-statements

I'm creating a function in a class wherein when I search for an item type for instance car then it will list all items that fall under the type car. I'm able to print all without the elif else condition, but when I add it I get a syntax error. This is probably due to me returning the values outside the elif else block. See comment on code. What should I change or add on my code?

```
    def get_item_type(self, types1):
        bool = True
        output = []
        output2 = (bool, output)

        for types2 in self.all_items:
            if types2.toy_type.lower() == types1.lower():
                output.append(types2.name)   
    
        return(output2)  #<<<<<This is where the problem is, indenting this works but doesn't return all items

            elif self.all_items == 0:
                bool = False
                output = (bool, 'The toy box is empty.')
                return output


            else:
                bool = False
                output = (bool, f'There are no toys of type {types1} in the toybox')
                
                return output
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `output2` and why are you trying to return it?

Comment: This is to show all items of the same type and return a bool.

Comment: Output of that looks like this: (True, ['Big Ted', 'Poorly Ted'])

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't call a variable `bool` because you overwrite the builtin [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool).

Comment: I see, what's your suggestion to return the bool value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
def get_by_toy_type(self, types1):
    bool = True
    output = []
    output2 = (bool, output)

    # Check if there are any toys
    if self.all_toys == 0:
        bool = False
        output = (bool, 'The toy box is empty.')
        return output

    # There are toys, find the car toys and add them to output
    for types2 in self.all_toys:
        if types2.toy_type.lower() == types1.lower():
            output.append(types2.name)

    # If cars found
    if len(output2) != 0:
        return output2

    # If cars not found
    else:
        bool = False
        output = (bool, f'There are no toys of type {types1} in the toybox')
        return output
```

I wouldn't recommend using 'bool' as a variable since it has a meaning in programming

Comment: Nice. Can you let me know how was the code able to return all items even if the "return output2" isn't inline with the For Loop? As I was only able to return all items if under the For Loop and not inside the the If Block. SO just trying to understand it. But it does work. Cheers.

Comment: The variable is defined at the start of the file outside the loops, so you are able to access it anywhere in the function and return it.